# Confusion about use of scope resolution operator in STL

Tags: c++, stl

The book I'm learning C++ from includes examples like this:

```
const int numMembers = tuple_size<tupleType>::value;
```

And this:

```
vector <int>::iterator arrIterator = intArray.begin ();
```

In both cases, it's not entirely clear to me how the scope resolution operator (::) is being used. How exactly are the values of value and iterator determined, respectively, in these examples?

Comment: Both elements exists inside each class `tuple_size<T>` and `vector<T>` respectively. The value of `tuple_size<tupleType>::value` depends on that implementation, i guess it is extracted when you declare your `tupleType`. For the case of vector, the value is assigned with `intArray.begin()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, the qualified name is used to name a member of the class template specialization.  This can be used to name a static class member.  Also, a `typedef` or `using` alias can appear in a class definition or class template definition, and the type alias name is considered a member of the class.

`std::tuple_size<tupleType>::value` is a static member (which specifies the number of elements in the tuple type).  `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a member class type (and objects of that type can be used to iterate over the vector's elements).

For example:

```
template <typename T> class A
{
public:
    static const int value = 3;
    typedef int number_type;
    using param_type = T;
    using container_type = std::vector<T>;
};

int main() {
    int a = A<int>::value;          // a is initialized to 3
    A<int>::number_type n = 0;      // n is an int
    A<int>::param_type p = 1;       // p is an int
    A<double>::param_type q = 2.5;  // q is a double
    A<double>::container_type v;    // v is a std::vector<double>
}
```

(As the example shows, a member of a class template can depend on template arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `tuple_size<tupleType>::value`, `value` is a variable defined inside the `tuple_size` struct. The `::` means something like 'look for the name value defined inside the tuple_size struct'.

The same goes for `vector <int>::iterator`. The `iterator` is defined inside the `vector` class.

You might be confused because both outer types in your examples have a template parameter specified. Looking at the `vector<int>` example, this makes the iterator (defined **inside** the vector class) know about the type it will iterate over. That is why `iterator` is defined inside of `vector` in the first place.

In case of the `tuple_size<tupleType>::value` this is the number of arguments in the tuple. `value` in  this case is in integer that depends on the template parameters so it also has to be defined **inside** the tuple class.

Comment: Yes, the confusion had something to do with templating.

Answer (score 1):

The scope resolution operator only specifies where to look for a name. So `tuple_size<tupleType>::value` means to look for the name `value` inside the class `tuple_size<tupleType>`. Scope resolution doesn't care what the name denotes, it only deals with where it is looked up.

The place where the name is used, is what determines whether or not it is a valid use.

In the first case, it is used in a declaration as an initializer, so it must name a value to be valid, and the compiler will complain if it doesn't. While in the second case, it is used in a declaration to name a type (`iterator`). Again, the compiler can check it is indeed a type once it examines the declaration and knows it should be one.

That is a slight simplification, of course. In the definition of templates, where those names are dependent on template parameters, the meaning can change. So we must specify explicitly what we expect those names to be, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Answer (score 1):

`tuple_size<tupleType>` and `vector<int>` are template classes. The template parameters `tupleType` and `int` are a part of the class definition, that means a `vector<double>` for example is a completely different class.

That's why you have to include them to resolve the scope.

In the end it's not different from accessing a simple class member like `class::member`.

Comment: What sort of member is iterator?

Comment: `vector::iterator` is a class. (a typedef probably).

Comment: Oh right, so vector in this case is just the namespace?

Comment: @Sadiq - No, the vector is a class, not a namespace. Both classes and namespaces have **scope**.

Comment: Alright, then it's a class with a class member? Interesting.

Comment: It's a class inside a class, or a "member class".